# Installing EPD on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python

I need to install [Enthought Python Distribution](https://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php) onto my desktop so that when I go to Uni I will have the same software as the desktops in class.

I have tried to download it and run the .sh file as an executable file and the terms and condition page loads up.  When I scroll down the page it finishes and the page closes.

I have tried every single version and i am still having difficulties. I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to explain what kind of file you received from the company? Is is a .deb, a .sh, etc? Do you have difficulties with the installation process, or did you actually finish the install but the result is buggy?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you received a .sh file from the company that sells EPD, and that you downloaded that file into the folder named "Downloads". What you should do is to try running the .sh file as the Super User

Here is a step-by-step explanation on how to do it.

- Hit the SUPER key ("Windows" key) on your keyboard. Type in "Terminal", and then hit enter. This launches the terminal window.
- Travel to the folder where EPD is saved, using the `cd` command. For instance, if you downloaded it into "Downloads", you should use `cd ~/Downloads/`.
- Then run your program with Super User rights. Let's assume your file is a Bash script, with a .sh extension. Let's also assume the name of the installer is "installerfilename.sh". To run your installer with super-user rights, you should type `sudo bash installerfilename.sh` in the terminal, hit Enter and then enter your password when it is asked for. Another possible command is `sudo ./installerfilename.sh`.

This should have installed EPD.
If you still run into any issues, please paste in your question the output that you got from the terminal after this command.

Comment: im a novice..... basically im very new at this any chance u cud do it step by step for me please :)

Comment: ok i have the files on my computer. but i dont know what to do with them.. they are in folders bin lib etc..

Comment: `bin` is usually where programs that you can run are called. Try `cd bin` (change to the bin directory), then `ls` (list files). You should be able to run those files with commands like `./ipython`